# How wild can regulated functions be?

Tags: real-analysis

A [regulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulated_function) $f$: $[a, b]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ has countably many points of discontinuity. Can the set $D$ of discontinuities be dense in $[a, b]$? What's an example?

In fact, can we find such an $f$ for any prescribed countable set $D\subseteq [a, b]$ of discontinuities?

Comment: They can be dense: see for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449244/function-defined-by-a-sum-using-rational-numbers (Using the method described in that question, you can construct such a $f$ for any countable $D$).

Comment: The Thomae (or Dirichlet) function has $D=\mathbb{Q}$. See the last example: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html

Comment: But the Dirichlet function is not regulated.

Comment: I edited the question. Hope that is what you mean by a regulated function..

Comment: @JohnMa yes, I just realized that your method works for any $D$. I'll accept if you post this as an answer below.

Comment: [This link](https://books.google.fr/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&pg=PA28#v=onepage&q&f=false) provides an example of a monotonic (hence regulated) function, defined on $\mathbf R$, with an *arbitrary* prescribed (countable) set of discontinuities.

Comment: Nice, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D \subset [0,1]$ be any countable set. Then, as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449244/function-defined-by-a-sum-using-rational-numbers), write

$$D = \{r_1, r_2, \cdots, r_n, \cdots\}$$
and

$$f(x) = \sum_{ r_n <x} \frac{1}{2^n}.$$

One can check that this is regulated and discontinuous precisely at $D$.

Comment: Do you know if there is also a regulated function, for which the left- and right limit are equal everywhere, yet $f$ is discontinuous precisely on $D$?